# Mockito method throwing null pointer exception for variable used

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

Iam using mockito to perform testing and iam very much new to it.
   Iam getting a null pointer exception in the Mockito method and in the Onmessage method for the use of a object/variable declared.
   The code snippet is as below.

**Class A.java**

```
        Class A{

        @Inject
        CheckConnection connection;

        public void onMessage(Message m)
        {
            if(connection.IsInternetavailable==true) //Null pointer is occuring here
            {
               //Do something with Message 
            } 
            else
            {
              //Do something with Message 
            }
         }
       }
```

**Class Atest.java-Mockito Class**

```
        Class ATest
        {

         @InjectMocks
         A resource;

         @Mock
            CheckConnection connection;

         @Test
            public void shouldProcessMessage() throws JMSException {
                // Arrange
                final String Type = "MessageType";
                final String Body = "MessageBody"

                final ActiveMQTextMessage message = new ActiveMQTextMessage();
                message.setStringProperty("messageType", Type);
                message.setText(Body);

                // Act
                this.resource.onMessage(message);  //This method fails i.e. it gives null pointer exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well ... You could begin with the exact code you are using. Your code snippets don't fit together: `CheckConnection != CheckInternetConnection` and `onMessage != OnMessage`. Additionally, if you have a mock, it does not automatically inject itself into the object under test.

Comment: i have corrected it now i think this sums it up

Comment: And what is `this.resource`? How could we possibly help you, if you simply keep back essential parts of your program?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Well, this. resource is the "A resource" declared on top of ATest class.

Comment: @GhostCat ... which he edited into the question _after_ my comment.

Comment: @ChetanSistla There is no annotation named `InjectMock` in Mockito.

Comment: [`InjectMocks` documentation](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) excerpt: _"Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection, setter injection, or property injection in order and as described below. If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito won't report failure; i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the annotation is `InjectMocks` not InjectMock **s** is missing

Second: You need to initialize the mocks with this call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` which should be in your set up method or first call in your test method.